# get user's choice from an input

Tags: c, input

I have a task to take an input from the user, using two methods.

I want to give the user chioce. If he wants method 1, press 1. Else, press 0.

Afterwards the user starts typing a string which I have to print. I print the input until the user presses enter button or EOF.

The problem is that when the user gives me his "choice" he presses the enter button ('\n') so my program exists.

How can I solve this?

```
printf("please enter your chioce: for malloc press 1. for linked list press 0\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    if (n)
    printWithMalloc();

    else{
.....
```

Just to be clear, my if for input:

```
printf("please enter a string. the string will be printed right away.\n");
    while ((c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n')
```

Comment: Do not use `printf (...)` for unformatted text output, this can be a bad habit that might lead you to try something really dangerous. If you were to print the user's input using `printf (user_input)` and the user [intentionally inserted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string) `%s` or `%n` in their input, they could crash your program or worse perform a callstack exploit. Make a habit of using `puts (...)` for single-line unformatted text output and only use `printf (...)` when you actually need to format your output.

Comment: Have you considered to scan the manual pages?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I don't agree with you. `printf` is completely fine, although you're are with the security concept, however this can be easily solved as `printf("%s\n", user_input);`

Answer (score 1):

**Just forget `scanf()`.**

---

If I understand your problem right, you want to exit when the user enters an **empty line.** If so, just read an entire line, and check if it is empty (apart from the trailing newline character):

```
while (1) {
    char buf[LINE_MAX];
    if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin))
        break; // EOF

    if (buf[0] == '\n')
        break; // empty line

    // if we got here, the user entered something; try converting it to an int
    int choice = strtol(buf, NULL, 0);
    // and do stuff with it
}
```

Comment: is there another option? I kinda afraid trying that with linked list and staff @H2CO3

Comment: @Alan What "another option"? There are endless options. And what does this have to do with linked lists? I'm not using any linked lists in this code.

Comment: I didn't want to enter a lot of code here, but baisicly I want it to be as simple as possible. The user enters an input to be put in a linked list at the end.

Comment: @Alan Aaaaand what's wrong with this code ^^ up here? Why does it prevent you from extending it in a manner that it appends or prepends a node to a link list?